# Arrayから要素を取得する際にエラーが出てしまいます

Tags: swift, ios, swift2

現在swiftでAppDelegateで宣言したNSMutableArrayの要素を別画面で保存・取得したいと思っています。 
（AppDelegateで宣言・初期化→A画面で保存→B画面で取り出し）

しかし、B画面で取得する時に

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

のエラーで止まってしまいます。 
ソースコードはこちらになります。

AppDelegate

```
var answerArray:NSMutableArray?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:
 [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        let answerArray = [0,0,0,0,0,0]
        print(answerArray)//[0,0,0,0,0,0]
}
```

aViewController

```
var answerArray:NSMutableArray?

override func viewDidLoad() {

            //bボタン
            q1_1btn = UIButton()
            q1_1btn.frame = CGRectMake(200,50,60,60)
            q1_1btn.setTitle("ボタンA", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            q1_1btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            q1_1btn.tag = 1
            q1_1btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(QuestionViewController.selectbtn(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
            self.view.addSubview(q1_1btn)
}
internal func selectbtn(sender: UIButton){
         print("sender.tag:\(sender.tag)") //1
         let appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
         //押したボタンのタグをarrayに格納
         let tag = sender.tag
         appDelegate.answerArray![0] = tag
                         let secondViewController = bViewController()
                         self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
}
```

bViewController

```
var str:NSArray?

override func viewDidLoad() {

            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor();
            let appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate 

            let num:Int = appDelegate.answerArray![0] as!Int //ここでfatal error
            print(appDelegate.answerArray) //nilと返されます

}
```

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/39505 マルチポスト

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`answerArray`という同名のローカル変数を宣言（シャドーイング）しているため、`AppDelegate`の`answerArray`は`nil`のままのためです。

`nil`をアンラップした結果、エラーとなる動作はSwiftの仕様通りです。

```
var answerArray:NSMutableArray?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:
 [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        // selfは必須ではないですが、明示のために    
        self.answerArray = [0,0,0,0,0,0]
        print(answerArray)//[0,0,0,0,0,0]
}
```